# How to write a full path in a batch file having a username with spaces?

Tags: batch-file, path

Essentially I am referencing a path in my batch file that includes the username.

Here is what I mean:

```
C:/users/%username%/
```

Using %username% does seem to work when refrecning the user currently logged in to the machine, but fails if the username has a space. For example the username ***jlows*** works no problem, but ***j lowes*** does not and shows an error saying user "j" cannot be found.

What can be added to the path to account for this situation?

Comment: We always enclose paths in double quotes to cater for whitespace i.e `cd "C:\users\%username%"`. anyway, as a shorter version you can use `cd "%USERPROFILE%"`

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`!

Comment: Your very first question on StackOverflow shows you quoting the paths. Also several answers provided to you shows paths being quoted.  Not sure where the disconnect is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always quote paths in batch files. This way, it helps you in order to avoid misbehaviours like this one. In most of the cases, system considers, e.g. the path `random` which doesn't exist because you have entered `random test`.

So, replacing `/` with `\` as this is the default Windows separator, will give you:

```bat
"C:\Users\%username%"
```

However, there is a shorter version, `userprofile`, which stands for `C:\Users\%username%`, exactly what you have. Use it like:

```bat
"%UserProfile%"
```